# A generic error occurred in GDI+ using WPF form

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, gdi+

Hi all I have the following code running behind a WPF form with 2 txt boxes on. 1 the src of the images, the other with the destination path.

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ProcessLbl.Content = "";
        string src = ImgSrc.Text;
        string dest = ImgDest.Text;
        string copyrightTxt = CopyWriteTxt.Text;
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(src, "*.jpg");
        MemoryStream ms = null;
        foreach (string f in filePaths)
        {
            try
            {
                ProcessLbl.Content += src + "\\" + f.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
                System.Drawing.Image thumbnail_image = null;
                System.Drawing.Image original_image = null;
                System.Drawing.Bitmap final_image = null;
                System.Drawing.Graphics graphic = null;
                original_image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(src,f));

                int width = original_image.Width;
                int height = original_image.Height;
                int target_width = 500;
                int target_height = 367;
                int new_width, new_height;

                float target_ratio = (float)target_width / (float)target_height;
                float image_ratio = (float)width / (float)height;

                if (target_ratio > image_ratio)
                {
                    new_height = target_height;
                    new_width = (int)Math.Floor(image_ratio * (float)target_height);
                }
                else
                {
                    new_height = (int)Math.Floor((float)target_width / image_ratio);
                    new_width = target_width;
                }

                new_width = new_width > target_width ? target_width : new_width;
                new_height = new_height > target_height ? target_height : new_height;
                final_image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(target_width, target_height);
                graphic = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(final_image);
                graphic.FillRectangle(new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#c2c6c9")), new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, target_width, target_height));
                int paste_x = (target_width - new_width) / 2;
                int paste_y = (target_height - new_height) / 2;

                graphic.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic; 
                graphic.DrawImage(original_image, paste_x, paste_y, new_width, new_height);
                final_image.Save(System.IO.Path.Combine(dest, f), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            }
            catch (Exception ResizeExp)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.StackTrace trace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(ResizeExp, true);  
                ProcessLbl.Content += Environment.NewLine;
                ProcessLbl.Content += Environment.NewLine;
                ProcessLbl.Content += ResizeExp.Message + " " + trace.GetFrame(0).GetFileLineNumber();
                ProcessLbl.Content += Environment.NewLine;
                ProcessLbl.Content += Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }
        //ProcessLbl
    }
}
```

I have some similar code running on a web page and that works fine, but form some reason I get the error "A generic error occurred in GDI+"

can anyone help?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have appropriate permission to save the Bitmap in the destination specified.
Try using a different location and see if the error resolves.If you need to use this location itself you will need to acquire admin rights via manifest modification.